# ADS Service is not supported by server

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I have a TwinCat 3 configuration with an EK1100 terminal and EL6731 Profibus terminal.
The EL6731 is configured as a separate device and has Profibus boxes underneath it, which are integrated with GSD files.

An external program, which can access the EtherCAT components via the TwinCat ADS interface, is used to control the outputs of the Profibus boxes.

e.g. one output of the profibus box has the following address.
IGrp: 0x8001
IOffs: 0xA
When I now try to write to this output via the ADS interface, I get the error message "Service is not supported by server (Ads-Error 0x701)"

However, if i write the output via the automatically created outputs in the EtherCat terminal via the ADS interface, the ADS write command works.
Here the address is then IGrp: 0xF20 and IOffs: 0x13A.

Must something be activated on the Profibus terminal so that the ADS commands that are addressed to the profibus box address work, instead to use the automatically created outputs underneath the EtherCat terminal?